# monitor session change event in c

Tags: c, session, service

I try to build a service that monitor user sessions activity. currently focusing on logon and lock of user.
i am using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540475(v=VS.85).aspx example

my code :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")

#define SVCNAME TEXT("SvcName")
#define SVC_ERROR 4

SERVICE_STATUS          gSvcStatus;
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE   gSvcStatusHandle;
HANDLE                  ghSvcStopEvent = NULL;
VOID SvcInstall(void);
DWORD WINAPI SvcCtrlHandler(DWORD , DWORD , LPVOID , LPVOID );

VOID WINAPI SvcMain(DWORD, LPTSTR *);

VOID ReportSvcStatus(DWORD, DWORD, DWORD);
VOID SvcInit(DWORD, LPTSTR *);
VOID SvcReportEvent(LPTSTR);



void __cdecl _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{

if (lstrcmpi(argv[1], TEXT("install")) == 0)
{
    SvcInstall();
    return;
}

SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY DispatchTable[] =
{
    { SVCNAME, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)SvcMain },
    { NULL, NULL }
};

if (!StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(DispatchTable))
{
    SvcReportEvent(TEXT("StartServiceCtrlDispatcher"));
}
}

VOID SvcInstall()
{
SC_HANDLE schSCManager;
SC_HANDLE schService;
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];

if (!GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH))
{
    printf("Cannot install service (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}

schSCManager = OpenSCManager(
    NULL,                    // local computer
    NULL,                    // ServicesActive database 
    SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);  // full access rights 

if (NULL == schSCManager)
{
    printf("OpenSCManager failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}

// Create the service

schService = CreateService(
    schSCManager,              // SCM database 
    SVCNAME,                   // name of service 
    SVCNAME,                   // service name to display 
    SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,        // desired access 
    SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, // service type 
    SERVICE_AUTO_START,      // start type 
    SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,      // error control type 
    szPath,                    // path to service's binary 
    NULL,                      // no load ordering group 
    NULL,                      // no tag identifier 
    NULL,                      // no dependencies 
    NULL,                      // LocalSystem account 
    NULL);                     // no password 

if (schService == NULL)
{
    printf("CreateService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
    return;
}
else printf("Service installed successfully\n");

CloseServiceHandle(schService);
CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
}

VOID WINAPI SvcMain(DWORD dwArgc, LPTSTR *lpszArgv)
{

gSvcStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(SVCNAME,SvcCtrlHandler,NULL);
OutputDebugString(L"\n***SVCMAIN");
if (!gSvcStatusHandle)
{
    SvcReportEvent(TEXT("RegisterServiceCtrlHandler"));
    return;
}

gSvcStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
gSvcStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;

ReportSvcStatus(SERVICE_START_PENDING, NO_ERROR, 3000);

SvcInit(dwArgc, lpszArgv);
}

VOID SvcInit(DWORD dwArgc, LPTSTR *lpszArgv)
{
FILE *f = fopen("c:\\test\\file.txt", "a");
OutputDebugString(L"\n***SVCINIT");
fprintf(f, "init\n");
fclose(f);

ghSvcStopEvent = CreateEvent(
    NULL,    // default security attributes
    TRUE,    // manual reset event
    FALSE,   // not signaled
    NULL);   // no name

if (ghSvcStopEvent == NULL)
{
    ReportSvcStatus(SERVICE_STOPPED, NO_ERROR, 0);
    return;
}

ReportSvcStatus(SERVICE_RUNNING, NO_ERROR, 0);

while (WaitForSingleObject(ghSvcStopEvent, 3000) != WAIT_OBJECT_0){
    OutputDebugString(L"\n***BEEP");

    f = fopen("c:\\test\\file.txt", "a");
    fprintf(f, "beep\n");
    fclose(f);
    Beep(1000, 100);

}
ReportSvcStatus(SERVICE_STOPPED, NO_ERROR, 0);

}

VOID ReportSvcStatus(DWORD dwCurrentState,
DWORD dwWin32ExitCode,
DWORD dwWaitHint)
{
static DWORD dwCheckPoint = 1;
DWORD my_error = 0;

// Fill in the SERVICE_STATUS structure.

gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState = dwCurrentState;
gSvcStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = dwWin32ExitCode;
gSvcStatus.dwWaitHint = dwWaitHint;
gSvcStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_SESSIONCHANGE | SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP;

if ((dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING) ||
    (dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOPPED)){   
gSvcStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
}
else gSvcStatus.dwCheckPoint = dwCheckPoint++;

// Report the status of the service to the SCM.
SetServiceStatus(gSvcStatusHandle, &gSvcStatus);
my_error = GetLastError();
FILE *f = fopen("c:\\test\\file.txt", "a");
fprintf(f, "last error  %d  \n",my_error);
fprintf(f, "\n***controls accepted %d ***\n",     gSvcStatus.dwControlsAccepted);
fclose(f);

}

DWORD WINAPI SvcCtrlHandler(DWORD dwControl, DWORD dwEventType, LPVOID     lpEventData, LPVOID lpContext)
{
DWORD dwErrorCode = NO_ERROR;

FILE *f = fopen("c:\\test\\file.txt", "a");
// Handle the requested control code. 
fprintf(f, "dwCtrl is = %d \n", dwControl);
fclose(f);

switch (dwControl)
{

case SERVICE_CONTROL_TIMECHANGE:
    f = fopen("c:\\test\\file.txt", "a");
    fprintf(f, "time\n");
    fclose(f);
    OutputDebugString(L"\n****GOT time!!!\n\n");
    SetEvent(ghSvcStopEvent);
    ReportSvcStatus(gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState, NO_ERROR, 0);
    break;

case SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE:
    f = fopen("c:\\test\\file.txt", "a");
    fprintf(f, "session\n");
    fclose(f);
    OutputDebugString(L"\n****GOT Session!\n\n");
    SetEvent(ghSvcStopEvent);
    ReportSvcStatus(gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState, NO_ERROR, 0);
    break;

case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
    OutputDebugString(L"\n****GOT STOP!\n\n");
    f = fopen("c:\\test\\file.txt", "a");
    fprintf(f, "stop\n");
    fclose(f);
    ReportSvcStatus(SERVICE_STOP_PENDING, NO_ERROR, 0);

    SetEvent(ghSvcStopEvent);
    ReportSvcStatus(gSvcStatus.dwCurrentState, NO_ERROR, 0);

    return;

case SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE:

    break;

default:
    break;
}

}

VOID SvcReportEvent(LPTSTR szFunction)
{
HANDLE hEventSource;
LPCTSTR lpszStrings[2];
TCHAR Buffer[80];

hEventSource = RegisterEventSource(NULL, SVCNAME);

if (NULL != hEventSource)
{
    StringCchPrintf(Buffer, 80, TEXT("%s failed with %d"), szFunction, GetLastError());

    lpszStrings[0] = SVCNAME;
    lpszStrings[1] = Buffer;

    ReportEvent(hEventSource,        // event log handle
        EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE, // event type
        0,                   // event category
        SVC_ERROR,           // event identifier
        NULL,                // no security identifier
        2,                   // size of lpszStrings array
        0,                   // no binary data
        lpszStrings,         // array of strings
        NULL);               // no binary data

    DeregisterEventSource(hEventSource);
}
}
```

any ideas why i am not getting any  "case SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE" and only stop?
in my log file i see the beep log and controls accepted - 129 (stop + session change)
this is my log file content :

```
last error  0  

***controls accepted 129 ***
init
last error  0  

***controls accepted 129 ***
beep
beep
beep
beep
beep
```

Answer (score 1):

gSvcStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(SVCNAME,SvcCtrlHandler,NULL);

should be :
gSvcStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(SVCNAME,SvcCtrlHandler,NULL);